# Can Fixnum/Float be nil?

Tags: ruby, null, fixnum

Can a Fixnum/Float be nil? Like can self even be nil in this case:

```
class Fixnum
  def clamp(min, max)
    if self == nil then nil end
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible because `nil` has its own class,`NilClass`:

```
irb(main):001:0> nil.class
=> NilClass
irb(main):002:0> 456.class
=> Fixnum
```

So a variable can either be a `Fixnum` or a `NilClass` but not both.

In the context of a class instance method,  `self` always refers to the instance, which is of the type of the class.

Also `self` cannot be changed:

```
irb(main):006:0> class C
irb(main):007:1>   def z
irb(main):008:2>     self = nil
irb(main):009:2>   end
irb(main):014:1> end
SyntaxError: (irb):8: Can't change the value of self
self = nil
      ^
        from D:/dev/Ruby20/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ask Ruby:

```
nil.is_a? Fixnum
# false
nil.is_a? Float
# false
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Object is either kind of Fixnum or NilClass. `self` is always a type of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The only way `self` could possibly equal `nil` is if you're inside `NilClass`.

```
class NilClass
  def self_is_nil?
    self == nil
  end
end

nil.self_is_nil? # => true
```